# ListView of ListView с только одним SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть `ArrayList<Screen>`, каждый Screen - это  `ArrayList<App>` и я предствляю их с помощью  ListView of ListView.

**Проблема** в SelectedItem, так как сейчас можно иметь несколько SelectedItem, то есть как Selected отображается 1 эллемент и в первом списке , и во втором.
Как можно ограничить, что бы мог быть только один SelectedItem App?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а почему нельзя использовать обычный `ListView`, а не `ListView из ListView`